# How to solve the double integral equation $\int_0^1\int_x^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{e^y}{y}\,dy\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^1\int_x^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{e^y}{y}\,dy\,dx$$

The main problem for this is I don't know how to integrate $\dfrac{e^y}{y}$, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do u know how to change order of integration?

Comment: The integral really simplifies. This trick it's new for me. Nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the region over wich the integration runs: the points between the straight line $y=x$ and the arc of the parabola $y=\sqrt x$. Putting $x$ as function of $y$, the limits are $x=y^2$ and $x=y$. The intersections are at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$

[image]

$$\int_0^1\int_x^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{e^y}{y}\,dy\,dx=\int_0^1\int_{y^2}^y\frac{e^y}{y}\,dx\,dy=$$

$$\int_0^1\left[x\frac{e^y}{y}\right]_{y^2}^y\,dy=\int_0^1\left(y\frac{e^y}{y}-y^2\frac{e^y}{y}\right)\,dy=$$

$$=\int_0^1\left(e^y-ye^y\right)\,dy=\left[e^y-(y-1)e^y\right]_0^1=e-2$$